# Enviar video y fotos por REST service POST swift

Tags: swift, swift4

tengo un problema al enviar datos en bytes por medio de un rest service, uso el estándar URLSession, en una llamada normal el servicio obtiene la respuesta de manera correcta pero cuando envÍo un dato en String con formato de Bytes ya no obtiene la respuesta correcta.

Los bytes son videos y fotos que yo genero tomando una imagen o video capturado.

Mi request tiene la siguiente forma. los parámetros que dicen Base64 son los que envío en ese formato, algo  a si como: 
     JKANSLJNDASUIDNASDLNSALDKJASL-.ASDNNIOASDNSAIODSAÑDISADNASIDOANASDNASODIASNDIASND.......

{
      "dato1":"correo@correo",
     "dato2":1,
     "video":{
     "nomVideo":"video.mp4",
     "TipVideo":"mp4",
     "ArchVideo":"Base64"
    },
    "listaImagen":[{
      "NomImagen":"imagen1.jpg",
      "TipImagen":"jpg",
      "ArchImagen":"base64"
     },
     {
     "NomImagen":"imagen2.jpg",
      "TipImagen":"jpg",
      "ArchImagen":"base64"
    }],
     "ObjetoPrincipal":{
     "objetoDato1":"Dato X",
     "objetoDato2":Dato Y"
      }
     }

utilizo JSONEncoder generar el JSON que envío como parámetro.

```
     var jsonString = ""
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(objeto)
        jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
        //print("JSON String : " + jsonString)
    }
    catch {
    }
```

y realizo una llamada normal con header de autorizacion:

```
let url = URL(string: url as String)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! )
    //var request = URLRequest(url: url! );
    request.httpMethod = POST
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue(authorizationParam, forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")

    let data = data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest,from: data, completionHandler: { (data,response, error ) in


        closure(data ,response, error)
        return
    })

    task.resume()
```

Comment: hay muchos problemas al querer enviar videos, usando peticiones a los servidores directamente como data, una solución que ha servido mucho es crear un proyecto en firebase, guardar los videos y fotos en Storage, al backend le envīas las urls de los videos y fotos que se guardan por usuario o por id, en vez de los videos y fotos como data, en caso de fotos suelen enviarse como base64 pero no recomiendo esto... al guardar las urls solo se le manda un String al backend, así al hacer la petición del back se recuperan las fotos y videos como urls y no como data. puedes usar SDWebImage para eso.

Comment: Te refieres a que desde el servidor obtener los archivos haciendo una peticion a los celulares ?

Comment: no, los archivos se guardan en el servidor de Firebase, tu obtienes esa url, la y la guardas en tu api, pero en vez de los archivos mandas las urls a tu api, esas y cuando haces una llamada a esos archivos, no mandas llamar los archivos... mandas llamar las urls, y vas a visualizar la foto o video... te recomiendo un tutoríal... checalo, te va ayudar mucho https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1vrjt7Nvb0&index=5&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq

Comment: gracias lo revisare